# Score component in beginner C++ program

Tags: c++

I am doing an assignment where I am supposed to write a program to test the user's math skills. Here's the code i have right now:

```
using namespace std;
void addition()
{
    int Value, Value2, Answer;
    bool gotAnswer;

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        Value = 1 + (rand()%10);
        Value2 = 1 + (rand()%10);

        gotAnswer = false;
        cout << Value << " + " << Value2 << " = ";

        for (int a=1; (a<=3 && gotAnswer==false); a++)
        {
            cin >> Answer;
            if (Answer==(Value+Value2))
            {
                cout << "CORRECT" << endl << endl;
                gotAnswer = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "WRONG Try again." << endl;
                if (a==3)
                {
                    cout << "You have missed 3 times. The answer is " << Value+Value2 << "." << endl << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

void substraction()
{
    int Value, Value2, Answer;
    bool gotAnswer;

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        Value = 1 + (rand()%10);
        Value2 = 1 + (rand()%10);

        gotAnswer = false;
        cout << Value << " - " << Value2 << " = ";

        for (int a=1; (a<=3 && gotAnswer==false); a++)
        {
            cin >> Answer;
            if (Answer==(Value-Value2))
            {
                cout << "CORRECT" << endl << endl;
                gotAnswer = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "WRONG Try again." << endl;
                if (a==3)
                {
                    cout << "You have missed 3 times. The answer is " << Value-Value2 << "." << endl << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Multiplication()
{
    int Value, Value2, Answer;
    bool gotAnswer;

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        Value = 1 + (rand()%10);
        Value2 = 1 + (rand()%10);

        gotAnswer = false;
        cout << Value << " x " << Value2 << " = ";

        for (int a=1; (a<=3 && gotAnswer==false); a++)
        {
            cin >> Answer;

            if (Answer==(Value*Value2))
            {
                cout << "CORRECT" << endl << endl;
                gotAnswer = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "WRONG Try again." << endl;
                if (a==3)
                {
                    cout << "You have missed 3 times. The answer is " << Value*Value2 << "." << endl << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter the number for the problem type desired:"<<endl;
    cout << "  1. Addition"<<endl;
    cout << "  2. Subtraction"<<endl;
    cout << "  3. Multiplication"<<endl;

    cin >> number;

    if (number == 1)
    {
        addition();
    }
    else if(number == 2)
    {
        substraction();
    }
    else if (number ==3)
    {
        Multiplication();
    }
}
```

The program runs fine. However, there should be a score component where the user gets 10 points on the first try, 5 point on second try, and 0 on third try/wrong. I have no idea how to blend the score component in and the display at the end of 10 questions. Hints please?

All thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep a score variable in each of your functions, add to the score variable as necessary and then return the score variable.

So those function are no longer going to be voids, they'll be ints. You can then get the score at the end and print it out.

I'm not going to write any code for you, since it is for an assignment :P

Comment: Thanks you! I tried adding a score component but it didn't return. After I changed to int, it kind of worked. Thanks!

Comment: I would keep the score local to main and have the functions return int values that are score deltas. so you would change the calls to addition(), subtraction() and multiplication() to score += addition(), etc. There's no reason to pass the current score in to the function. The function evaluates the user's performance independently of prior result.